# tf.TFRecordReader will never exhausted

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here is my code of reading data from tfrecords: tfrecords contails 10,000 sample

```
def read_notmnist(filename_queue):
  """
  Read examples from notmnist tfrecords data
  :param filename_queue: a Queue of strings with the filenames to read from
  :return:
  image: a [IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE,1] uint8 tensor represent image data.
  label: a int32 Tensor with the label in the range 0 - (NUM_CLASSES-1)
  """
  reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
  _, serialize_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

  features = tf.parse_single_example(
    serialize_example,
    features={
      'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
      'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
    }
  )
  image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
  image = tf.reshape(image, [IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 1])

  label = tf.cast(features["label"], tf.int32)
  # pdb.set_trace()
  # label = tf.reshape(label,[])
  return image, label
```

I write a test program:

```
def main(unused_args):
    image,label = test_read_notmnist(data_dir=FLAGS.data_dir,batch_size=FLAGS.train_batch_size)

    print("start run")
    sess = tf.Session()
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    all_pass = True
    for i in range(100000000):
        # sess = tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess)
        image_run,label_run = sess.run([image,label])
        all_pass = all_pass and (image_run.shape == (FLAGS.train_batch_size, 28, 28, 1) ) and \
                   (label_run.shape == (FLAGS.train_batch_size,))
        # print("Sample Processed {0}".format((i+1)*(FLAGS.train_batch_size)))
        print("Sample Processed {0}".format((i+1)))
```

The for loop can run 100000000 times without any error. I don't find any parameter to customize this behavior, what should I do if I want the all the data only once (in a validation scenario, I only want inference every example from validation dataset exactly once)

Comment: Queues will infinitely dequeue unless set num_epoch (I.e in your filename_queue, num_epoch should be set to num_files)  Infinite dequeue is default behavior.

Comment: thanks. I check `tf.TFRecordReader` and `tf.train.batch`. but forget to check `tf.train.string_input_producer`

Comment: TFRecordDataset and its enumerate method seems to serve your need: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/TFRecordDataset